# file_get_contents() not working properly

Tags: php, curl, header, file-get-contents

Any ideas why file_get_contents() is not working properly on server A but works on server B for certain websites?

```
$f = file_get_contents("https://developer-api.nest.com/devices.json?auth=c.GGU9iS...");
```

This echoes absolutely nothing on server A, but it works on server B, I've tested everything...

a) allow_url_fopen is ON

b) If I do file_get_contents(); getting another website, it works on both servers.

c) I've tried using cURL and still got nothing on server A but does get something on server B.

d) I've tested cURL with another website and it does work both servers.

e) Tried to do `var_dump($http_response_header);` and returns NULL on server A.

I don't know what's going on, I've done anything.

**UPDATE:**

I did `wget https://developer-api.nest.com/devices.json?auth=c.GGU9iS...` on server A and it never connects, and just noticed it's using port **9553**, if I do this same `wget` on this other server (B) it works correctly. I'm so confused.

I echoed `curl_error();` and it returns **couldn't connect to host**, but it's working perfectly on my other server. This is driving me crazy.

Comment: Sounds like a rejected SSL cert or a blocked port.

Comment: did you do a `var_dump($f)`? There's a major difference between "nothing as in boolean false", which means failure, and "nothing as in empty string", which means it worked and the nest.com server sent you nothing.

Comment: I'm getting `string(0) ""` when I do `var_dump($f)` :(

Comment: @MattS SELINUX is disabled, so as far as I know it shouldn't be blocking any port

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it.

I added the port to the iptables that the url is using, as it's not an "normal" port and restarted my firewall and worked perfectly.

Thank you.